# Cant find PopUpButtonPickerStyle in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

I wanted to use the PopUpButtonPickerStyle for my Picker which i use in a Form, but it just does not exist for me. Any other PickerStyle thats in the Apple documentation works.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear from the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/popupbuttonpickerstyle) that PopUpButtonPickerStyle is only available on macOS 10.15+ and not on iOS.

Since you marked your question with the "ios" tag I am assuming you are building iOS app indeed and thus you cannot use it.